# how to get the future value in build widget

Tags: flutter

i made a future function which return bool value, then i used it in the build widget on if condition but the code is always returning the sign in.
can any one help me solving this issue.

```
 Future isExist(uid) async{
    var isExist = await Database().checkIfUserExist(uid);
    if(isExist == true){
      return true;
    }
    else{
      return false;
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final user = Provider.of<UserDashboard?>(context);
    // return either Home or Authenticate widget
    if(user == null){
      print("user null");
      return SignIn();
    }else{
      print("user not null");
      if(isExist(user.uid) == Future.value(true)){
        return Home();
      }
    }
    return SignIn();
  }
```

user is not null and is exist but not taking the correct result.

```
Future<bool> checkIfUserExist(String adminID) async{
bool isExist = false;
try{
  await admin.doc(adminID).get()
    .then((doc) => isExist = doc.exists);
  return isExist;
}catch(e){
  print(e);
  return isExist;
}
}
```

the above function is safe and good because i used it in another screen and worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try using FutureBuilder for future method.

```dart
 FutureBuilder<bool>(
        future:  isExist(uid), // use a state variable for statefulwidget
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
             if(snapshot.data) return Home();
             else  return SignIn();
         }
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
 }
```

More about using [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)